# Shift + k opening man entry in a diff window

Tags: vim

My MacVim has started behaving strangely: when I use shift + k to look up the documentation for a command (in this case, using pydoc.vim), the split opens in the right-hand buffer of a diff split.

I've checked both my vimrc and my gvimrc, and I have no commands overriding shift + k, so I'm wondering where else I can begin to look for the problem.

Edit: after trying what sehe suggested, I got:

```
 diff
  scrollbind
  filetype=man
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/pydoc.vim
noswapfile
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/pydoc.vim
```

So it looks like pydoc.vim is the culprit here?

Comment: I think this should be moved to superuser.

Comment: Why? programmers don't read manpages or diff sources?

Comment: @urschrei: also, `:verbose map K` should list the mappings on K; perhaps you need to look for `:verbose map <Leader>K` (I'm no macvim user, so I can't really tell)

Comment: @sehe That worked fine, and didn't show a conflict or odd mapping, so I'm now pretty sure it's an issue with the pydoc.vim, and I've opened an issue on GitHub. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bruno vim questions belong on SO, as per a vote on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you have this reproduced, in the right diff pane (that will later be misused by man) do

```
:verbose se diff? scrollbind? filetype? swapfile? syntax?
```

After reproducing that, in the 'mixed up' window (right diff/man page), do the same again.

```
:verbose se diff? scrollbind? filetype? swapfile? syntax?
```

This might help shed some light on *what happens why*

---

#### Extra

*If you want, you can redirect the output like this for convenience*:

```
:redir >>/tmp/stackoverflow
:setlocal
:redir END
:tabedit /tmp/stackoverflow
```

$0.02

#### Update 23:02 CEST

> So it looks like pydoc.vim is the culprit here?

Most definitely. You might want to temporarilty disable it (e.g. move it out of the way). Does it fix it? Then you might look for updates of pydoc.vim or report an issue with the maintainer (*assuming you don't see an obvious fix in the script :)*)

#### After burner

Since the answer has been accepted, I sort of gather things have been resolved? I just thought of the following logical next step in analysis: check that pydoc hasn't just hijacked the mapping:

```
 :verbose map K
```

should list the mappings on K; perhaps you need to look for (I'm no macvim user, so I can't really tell)

```
 :verbose map <Leader>K
```